# vim cross-compiling for ARM

Tags: linux, vim, cross-compiling, ncurses

I'm using **arm-linux-gnueabi** and trying to compile **vim** for my device. After some time searching and studying I'm succeeded, but when I started it from device I see this:

```
# /usr/tmp/vim/bin/vim
~
...
~
~VIM - Vi IMprovedversion 7.4.873by Bram Moolenaar et al.Vim is open source and freely distributableSponsor Vim development!type  :help sponsor<Enter>    for informationtype  :q<Enter>to exittype  :help<Enter>  or  <F1>  for on-line helptype  :help version7<Enter>   for version infoRunning in Vi compatible modetype  :set nocp<Enter>for Vim defaultstype  :help cp-default<Enter> for info on this
```

**cursor does not move at any direction and text I type goes in single last line.** Vim commands works fine.

If it matters, during compilation I compiled **ncurses** library and target it with flags:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="<my_path>/lib/"
export CPPFLAGS="-L<my_path>/ncurses"
export LDFLAGS="-L<my_path>/lib"
```

but without `--with-tlib=ncurses` i had an error:

```
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... yes
ncurses library is not usable
```

I used installation manual for cross-compiling vim sources, according to witch I set some variables:

```
export vim_cv_terminfo=yes
export vim_cv_tty_group=world
export vim_cv_getcwd_broken=no
export vim_cv_stat_ignores_slash=yes
export vim_cv_memmove_handles_overlap=yes
export vim_cv_bcopy_handles_overlap=yes
export vim_cv_memcpy_handles_overlap=yes
export vim_cv_tgetent=non-zero
```

I'm not really sure about them...

I did some more research, but did not find any usable information.
This issue maybe relative to wrong **term** detection or ncurses compilation...

Maybe there is some flag I must set during compilation? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the resources you used or complete instructions to do this or a working script?  I am guessing you had to cross-compile all dependencies from source as well?  From your answer below, does the terminfo database just need to be present on the target at runtime?

Comment: As far as I remember I cross-compile only ncurses lib. Instructions to compile vim I found with source code of vim.
And yes, terminfo directory with term-files must be presented on target machine. It's kind a large, but You can leave only files you need.
If you stuck - feel free to ask me for help. Maybe I can remember something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure this out.

It's seems that vim needed **terminfo** database (ncurses lib creates it) to work properly.

I added part of the database to the device with terminals I use (vt100 and xterm) and it works fine now.
To find out location for terminfo database, I used **strace** command:

```
strace vim
...
stat64("/root/.terminfo", 0xc7a4c8)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/opt/share/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1024, ...}) = 0
...
```